# Java: ArrayList in Superclass

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having a terrible time with using an ArrayList in a superclass. The ArrayList is used to hold objects of three different types of subclasses of superclass Enemy. Depending on how I reference an object in the ArrayList in the driver file dictates different results.

Enemy is a child of a superclass called fighter. Fighter holds the private data for all of the objects.

Here is the superclass Enemy.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Enemy extends Fighter {
    public void getRandomEnemy(){};
    public ArrayList<Enemy> enemy = new ArrayList<Enemy>();

    Enemy(String wep, String arm, String nam, int health, int magResis, int physResis, int rangResis)
    {
        super(wep,arm,nam,health,magResis, physResis,rangResis);
    }
}
```

For Example:

Two of Enemy's subclasses Troll and Sorcerer have objects of their respective types added to the ArrayList found in the parent class Enemy.

Troll and Sorcerer Constructors:

```
Sorcerer(String wep, String arm, String nam, int health, int magResis, int physResis, int rangResis)
    {
        super(wep,arm,nam,health,magResis, physResis,rangResis);
    }

Troll(String wep, String arm, String nam, int health, int magResis, int physResis, int rangResis)
    {
        super(wep,arm,nam,health,magResis, physResis,rangResis);
    }
```

I am adding objects to the ArrayList in superclass enemy through these methods. Each method is found in its respective class.

```
public void getRandomEnemy()
    {
        enemy.add(new Troll("Bow", "Leather", "Troll",350, 30, 15,30));
    }

public void getRandomEnemy()
    {
        enemy.add(new Sorcerer("Staff", "Cloth", "Sorcerer",300, 70, 5,5));

    }
```

Now in my driver file if I add objects of types troll and sorcerer to the ArrayList in enemy as such.

Driver file:

```
int p = 5; // adds 5 enemies to the ArrayList enemy
int randEnemy = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < p; ++i)
        {

            randEnemy = (int) (Math.random() * (3));

            if(randEnemy == 0)
            {
                sorc.getRandomEnemy();
            }
            else if(randEnemy == 1)
            {
                trol.getRandomEnemy();
            }
            else
            {
                og.getRandomEnemy();
            }
        }
```

This is where I begin to run into issues.
For example, if I want to return the size of ArrayList enemy. The total size I have to do this in my driver file.

```
int size = sorc.enemy.size() + trol.enemy.size() + og.enemy.size();
```

I have to call each specific object type and add them together.

If I do Enemy.enemy.size(); It will return 0.

Again, things get fishy with the ArrayList when I want to attack an enemy.I have to specifically look for each Sorc object or Troll object in the ArrayList.

```
for(Enemy j : sorc.enemy)
                {   
                    System.out.println("Sorc's Health: " + j.getHealth());
                    System.out.println("Sorc's Armor: "+ j.getArmor());
                    sorc.takeDamage(attack, "Cloth", weapon);
                }
```

If I do the code above I will get the correct health for the Sorcerer which is 300 and I will get the correct armor. But, the Sorcerer will not take any damage.

If I do this:

```
for(Enemy j : sorc.enemy)
                {   
                    System.out.println("Sorc's Health: " + j.getHealth());
                    System.out.println("Sorc's Armor: "+ j.getArmor());
                    j.takeDamage(attack, "Cloth", weapon);
                }
```

The health will return -1999234 or some random negative value,but the takeDamage() method will work perfectly.

My question is why when I reference the object differently, I get different results? How do I properly reference the objects in the ArrayList to ensure the proper values are getting set? I am sure it isn't a logic error because I am setting the values in the constructors and calling the constructors in the getRandomEnemy() method to add objects to the ArrayList.

EDIT: Issue Fixed

In the superclass Fighter the constructor is defined as such.

```
public Fighter(String wep, String arm, String nam, int health, int magResis, int physResis, int rangResis)
    {
        this.name = nam;
        this.weapon = wep;
        this.armor = arm;
        this.health = health;
        this.magicResistance = magResis;
        this.physicalResistance = physResis;
        this.rangedResistance = rangResis;
    }
```

Health was giving me the issue. It was the only variable turning out wonky data. As you see, the parameter has int health, and I am setting that argument that is passed through to this.health = health;

Even though I am using this. to distinguish between the the parameter and the instance variable, the value was coming out negative.

I simply changed the constructor to this:

```
public Fighter(String wep, String arm, String nam, int hea, int magResis, int physResis, int rangResis)
    {
        this.name = nam;
        this.weapon = wep;
        this.armor = arm;
        this.health = hea;
        this.magicResistance = magResis;
        this.physicalResistance = physResis;
        this.rangedResistance = rangResis;
    }
```

and now everything works.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - you haven't provided enough information for us to help you yet.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Ok, I am on it! Sorry about that!

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated the code. If you need more output or if this isn't specific enough, I can add more/ change what is shown.

Comment: That's still not a short but complete program. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Please provide the constructor for Troll.

Comment: @JonSkeet That is a very detailed post.I see what you are saying. I'll try one more time.

Comment: @Demplo It has been added

Comment: Your use of `for` to iterate over elements in an array is correct. Also, nothing here seems to be directly related to the fact that you are subclassing anything. More likely, there is a logic- or scope-related flaw or typo somewhere. However, as you have not posted a minimal, relevant and complete example, it is not possible to tell where your problem lies. The thing about posting a minimal example is it also helps *you* get a *clear view* of your problem, which at the present time you do not have. This may lead you to a solution. It helps you as much as it helps us.

Comment: There are two problems with posting snippets of your actual program, rather than a short but complete program that shows the problem: you will keep getting requests for more pieces, and you are missing out on an opportunity to find the bug yourself by seeing what you need to reproduce it.

Comment: Now, with your edit, you're still missing the `Enemy` code, so we have no idea what is actually happening with the values you pass to the `Troll` constructor. (Illustrative of Patricia's point in the comment above.) I suggest that you temporarily delete this question, rework it, then undelete it.

Comment: @JasonC I apologize and I am working on it. I'll get more detailed and make a short program.

Comment: I don't get why a Troll (which is an enemy right?) should have a list of Enemy as a field.

Comment: @Demplo Enemies of your enemies are your friends?

Comment: @TheDude1142 OK... so now, what's a `Fighter`?

Comment: Oh I see...I would have designed it differently but that's fine.

Comment: @Demplo I am new to Java. I have programmed in other languages for a while, but Java is new to me. So I apologize for any newbie mistakes or anything like that.

Comment: It's not so much about being good at Java as it is about being good at asking questions! :) I suspect your problem is simple but you need to follow the advice at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://sscce.org/, those pages exist to help you, not just to take up space. The reality is that it is quicker for you to read them and follow the advice there than to continue this back and forth here, which has been ongoing for 45 minutes now.

Comment: @JasonC You're right, I am not asking a specific enough question. I appreciate you all being nice to me despite botching the question. I'll try and fix it. I guess I am just confusing myself on what dictates a short and complete program. Short enough for you all to run it? I am assuming so, I'll fix it.

Comment: Short enough that it demonstrates the problem without noise. Complete enough that it accurately demonstrates what you are doing and gives others something to work with. Note that making it "short" is an important general debugging step - it's *not* just for the convenience of others. While removing "noise" you may find that your problem no longer occurs; and now you have a good hint that that "noise" was actually the root cause. This is a good technique overall. While it's not always feasible to generate an SSCCE, of course, it's a good option if you don't actually know what info is relevant.

Comment: @JasonC I see what you are saying. Ok, I believe I know what I need to do. Thank you again.

Comment: Failure to find a bug is often due to looking in the wrong place. The act of stripping down a program to [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) or similar can reveal code that the programmer assumed was irrelevant but that is actually the source of the bug.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan This is very true. But, I am sure it is because I am not referencing the objects in the ArrayList correctly.

Comment: @JasonC I completely redid the question and localized it to exactly where the issue is happening and what occurs when it is happening. I hope this is some what better. If not, thank you for all of your help today. I'll probably just start my program over.

Comment: In order to answer your follow-up question of why you observe different results: 1) In the first array loop snippet, how, precisely, have you determined that the sorcerer's health is 300 and that the sorcerer has not taken damage? 2) In the second snippet, how, precisely, have you determined that `takeDamage()` is working perfectly?

Comment: @JasonC Well, I created single objects of each class during my testing and the takeDamage method worked like it was suppose to. I even checked all of the private variables of the objects in the ArrrayList and the only one posting negative values is the health. All of the other data is correct. It is the strangest thing.

Comment: @JasonC What is even stranger is I can go ahead and set the health to whatever I want after it has already been put in the ArrayList and the object's health will become that number. But, initially it starts off negative. Just strange. In the constructor I am setting it just like every other variable too.

Comment: @JasonC Everything works like it is supposed to once I go out of my way and reset the health. Honestly, I am dumbfounded right now.

Comment: @JasonC I swear this is the last piece of spam you will get from me haha. But, I fixed the issue. You might be interested to see what it was. I edited my question and posited it above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is a misunderstanding of how the members of a super class work.
When you declared:

```
public class Enemy extends Fighter {
    public ArrayList<Enemy> enemy = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
}
```

Every object of type `Enemy` or a subclass of `Enemy` will have their own instance of the `enemy` List. They will not share the same list.
Also you are mixing up different object members:

```
Sourcerer sourcer = new Sourcerer();
sourcer.getHealth(); // this is a member of the object just created;
sourcer.enemy;  // is a list of Enemy type objects
                // this list is a member of the sourcer object

for(Enemy enemy : sourcer.enemy) {
      enemy; //is an object in the list
            //this object should not be sourcer object (see below)
}

sourcer.enemy.add(sourcer); //is valid but will make a really big mess
                            //so make sure you never do this.
```

If you want your objects to share the same list from the super class, you need to declare it `static`.
I would suggest you make a separate class which manages the battle and have the list there. This way you separate the individual characters (Fighters, Enemies, Sorcerer, Trolls) from the management of groups of characters (battle).

Comment: I see what you are saying and thank you for your help. But, is there any reason why depending on how I referenced the ArrayList the results were different or why the values are being set?

Comment: @TheDude1142 Add some temporary debugging printouts to your various methods, or even better, step through it one line at a time in your debugger (if you're using e.g. Eclipse or NetBeans). This will let you follow exactly what is happening in both cases. Tip: Give each of your objects a unique name and print it (or at least `this.getClass().getSimpleName()`) in your trace print-outs to help you identify what is being called on what.

Comment: @JasonC You're the man JasonC. I learn more and more each day.

Comment: I expanded the answer to clarify why you see the different results.